# use pre-compiled tensorflow with cmake

Tags: c++, linker, tensorflow, clion

I've got a c++ project set up in **CLion** that uses **CMake**. I am using various 3rd party libraries and would like to also integrate **Tensorflow**.

I've tried **bazel** to compile **Tensorflow** to a shared library `libtensorflow.so` which kind of worked however there are still quite a few dependencies (e.g. to a current protobuf version and once I do that there are more) that I'd have to fix.

Is there a way to use the standard **Tensorflow** git repository and somehow link the libraries that are pre-compiled for python usage?  Or is there another convenient way?

Tensorflow in Python works well for me.

Answer (score 6):

I am aware this answer is quite late, but I encountered your exact problem and was able to solve it. I created a repository [here](https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake) that describes how to accomplish exactly what you want. The gist is:

- Add a build rule to the TensorFlow repository containing all of the required C++ elements.
- Build the shared library using Bazel and copy all headers to `/usr/local`.
- Install specific versions of Protobuf and Eigen (this is done automatically with scripts) or add them as external dependencies.
- Configure your CMake project with the given files.

If you have any questions or problems, don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Why do we need to put the files in the /usr/local? Can I just put my files somewhere else, and have Cmake find them directly instead? Thanks for the help with cmake

Comment: The linked project doesn't work with TF 1.4+ (the current TF version is 2.8).

Answer (score 5):

If you're on MacOS, using homebrew, CMake and `pkg_config` it's easy.

First get Tensorflow using brew:

```
brew install libtensorflow
```

Then in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(tf-inference)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(TensorFlow REQUIRED tensorflow)

link_directories(${TensorFlow_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_compile_definitions(${TensorFlow_CFLAGS_OTHER})

add_executable(tf-inference inference.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tf-inference ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})
```