# C++ program crashes with "illegal hardware instruction" error

Tags: c++

I know this has already been posted, but i couldn't find a solution to my issue. 
there are two files involved:

- `Camera(.cc|.h)`
- `CameraServer(.cc|.h)`

`Camera.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef myproject_CAMERASERVER_CAMERA_H
#define myproject_CAMERASERVER_CAMERA_H

#include <myprojectGlobal.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../ObjectDetection/FaceDetection.h"

namespace myproject::CameraServer {

    class Camera {
    private:
        bool showWindow;
        bool close;
        cv::VideoCapture capture;
        cv::Mat currentFrame;
        s16 cameraID;
    public:

        Camera(s16 CameraID, bool ShowWindow);
        i16 Open(bool faceDetection);
        void Close();
    };
}
#endif
```

`Camera.cc`:

```cpp
#include "Camera.h"

using namespace myproject::CameraServer;

Camera::Camera(s16 CameraID, bool ShowWindow) {
    cameraID = CameraID;
    showWindow = ShowWindow;
    close = false;
    printf("Initialized Camera Server for: %hd\n", cameraID);
}

i16 Camera::Open(bool faceDetection) {
    printf("Opening Camera Stream for: %hd\n", cameraID);
    if (showWindow) {
        cv::namedWindow("Test Capture", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    }
    printf("Opening Camera...");
    capture.open(cameraID);
    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        printf("Error with Camera: %hd\n", cameraID);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("done\n");

    printf("Loading Face Detection Configuration...");
    auto config = myproject::ObjectDetection::FaceDetection::LoadTemplateConfigurationFromAssets("./assets/OpenCV");
    printf("done\n");
    while(true) {
        printf("Processing Frame...");
        capture >> currentFrame;
        if (currentFrame.empty()) {
            printf("Frame is empty!\n");
            break;
        }
        if (faceDetection) {
            printf("Running Face Detection on Frame...");
            myproject::ObjectDetection::FaceDetection::DetectFace(currentFrame, config, 1.0f);
            printf("done\n");
        }
        if (showWindow) {
            printf("Drawing Frame on to Window...\n");
            cv::imshow("Test Capture", currentFrame);
            if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            printf("done\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`CameraServer.cc`:

```cpp
#include "CameraServer.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World from the CameraServer!\n");
    myproject::CameraServer::Camera camTest(0, true);
    i16 result = camTest.Open(true);
    printf("%i\n", result);
    return result;
}
```

this is the logs that the console procudes:

```
Initialized Camera Server for: 0
Opening Camera Stream for: 0
Opening Camera...done
Loading Face Detection Configuration...done
[1]    67973 illegal hardware instruction  ./myproject.CameraServer
```

- I'm using CMake with OpenCV
- working on a MacBook Pro 16 (Intel)
- only attached Webcam: integrated

Can someone help me or explain this to me?

Comment: Googling for "illegal hardware instruction DetectFace" all seem to point to the installation of TensorFlow.

Comment: i've added tensorflow to my project using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076914/use-pre-compiled-tensorflow-with-cmake), but i still get the same error message. I've checked the cmake logs, tensorflow was found and linked

Comment: determine which of those libraries, if any, is **required** to cause this. provide all conceivable debugging info.